# display more than one div on hover selector(image tag) using css

Tags: html, css

How to display two div on hover of image tag,
My html looks like this

```
<img class='itemImage'>
<div class='selctImgInptWrapper"> <input class='selctImgInpt' type='checkbox' value> </div>
<div class='selctImgInptRetouchWrapper"> <input class='selctImgInptRetouch' type='checkbox' value> </div>
```

CSS code

```
.selctImgInptWrapper { display: none; }
.selctImgInptRetouchWrapper { display: none; }

.itemImage:hover + .selctImgInptWrapper{ display: block; }
```

this code works for only one class either `selctImgInptWrapper` or `selctImgInptRetouchWrapper` 
I am not able to include both class at once

I tried

```
1) .itemImage:hover + .selctImgInptWrapper , .selctImgInptRetouchWrapper { display: block; }

2) .itemImage:hover + .selctImgInptWrapper .selctImgInptRetouchWrapper { display: block; }

3) .itemImage:hover + .selctImgInptWrapper ,.itemImage:hover + .selctImgInptRetouchWrapper { display: block; }
```

But none of the three worked

[image: UI for the above]

Comment: You can inbricate the `+` selector. You can do `img:hover + div ,  img:hover + div + div {display:block;}` You were very close ;) (add your class the same they appear in HTML)

Comment: why two times div in the second img:hover

Comment: because you have 2 divs behind your img, you want to acces the first one and the second one don't you ?  So if you use the + selector you have to go step by step, tag by tag in your html tree. You can use the ~ selector, but it is also good to know how to use the + selector. You may have some surprise with the ~ selector if you have other box with same class on the same level behind the 2 you wanna show ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors `The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element` **only if it immediately follows** `the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ~ symbol instead of the + symbol

This helps explain
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
.selctImgInptWrapper,
.selctImgInptRetouchWrapper {
    display:none;
}

.itemImage:hover ~ .selctImgInptWrapper {display:block;}
.itemImage:hover ~ .selctImgInptRetouchWrapper {display:block;}
```

In addition, be careful with your syntax as you seem to have a mix of single and double quotations on your class names.

```
<div class="selctImgInptWrapper">
```

Not as below as it could cause issues.

```
<div class='selctImgInptWrapper">
```

Also I find not using camel case for classes easier to read. I tend to leave the camelCase for the ids. This may also help.

```
<div class="select-img-input-wrapper">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the ~ selector

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

I recommend you to wrap the img and divs in a container div and class

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>

<style>
    div.wrapper > img:hover ~ div {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Sorry if anything might be wrong. I am posting this from my phone

Answer (score 0):

You can try solution also

- You can wrap all elements including `img` in one `div`. here i am
  using `main-container`
- Set `position: relative` to `.main-container`
- Wrap `checkboxes` in one `div`. here i have used `input-container`
  for that. set `display: none` to it
- Set `display: block` to `input-container` on `hover` of
  `main-container`

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px; /* You can change */
}
.input-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.main-container:hover .input-container{ display: block; }
```

```html
<!-- Main Wrapper -->
<div class="main-container">
  <img class="itemImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" slt="" />

  <!-- Checkbox wrapper -->
  <div class="input-container">
    <div class="selctImgInptWrapper"> 
      <input id="main" class="selctImgInpt" type="checkbox" value="" /> 
      <label for="main">Main</label>
    </div>
    <div class="selctImgInptRetouchWrapper"> 
      <input id="reTouch" class="selctImgInptRetouch" type="checkbox" value="">
      <label for="reTouch">Retouch</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```